# search part of text and edit numbers behind it

Tags: vb.net

I've got a text document such as this

```
N1 G17 G90
N3 G54
N5 M03
N7 G01 X-3.0 Y145.2501 F1000.0
N9 G01 Y142.7501 F500.0
N11 G01 X-0.5
N13 G01 Y145.2501
N15 G02 X291.0 Y145.25 I145.25 J145.25
N17 G01 X-0.5
N19 G03 X291.0 Y145.35 I145.25 J145.25
N21 G01 X293.5
N23 G01 Y142.85
N25 G01 X296.0
N27 G01 Y145.35
N29 G02 X587.5 Y145.3499 I441.75 J145.3499
N31 G01 X296.0
N33 G03 X587.4999 Y145.4499 I441.75 J145.3499
N35 G01 X592.4999
N37 M05
N39 M30
```

(This is CNC Code to move my milling machine)
X is the Left/right coordinates
Y is the front/back coordinates
Z is the up/down coordinates
I & J are coordinates for a circle

That said, 
I'm looking for a way to make an array of this file.
I've got 4 textboxes, and a button

```
txtBox_X_Amount = 'the amount the object should be placed in the X direction'
txtBox_X_Distance = 'The distance they should be placed'
txtBox_Y_Amount = 'the amount the object should be placed in the Y direction'
txtBox_Y_Distance ='The distance they should be placed'
btn_generate
```

if i press Generate i want it to hold the original file minus the last 2 lines N37 M05 and N39 M30(the N numbers of the last 2 lines are different everytime)
then i want to add txtBox_X_Distance to the number behind X of each line
and append this to the textfile
this i want to do as many times as my txtBox_X_amount.
the same goes for Y.
and at the end of

Can anyone explain how you can do this?
or point me in the right direction?

This is what i am looking for
The red arrow is just the file not edited.
So my milling machine would just do 1 arrow.
All the arrows together is what i need.
[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @N0Alias my question is if someone can help me with this, explain how to do it or point me in the right direction.
I've been searching but i can't seem to find a way to make it work.

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @DanielShillcock  added it to a richtextbox i can delete the first 3 lines and the last 2 lines i can append it multiple times.(but not edited). editing the value behind X and the value behind Y is the big problem

Comment: You could read a line at a time with a stream reader and as you go through the lines, re-build as needed. When you come upon a line that `Contains` one of your key letters (X,Y,Z,F,I,J) then you know it's time to split the line on the space character and then loop through the array from the split looking for elements that start with one of those letters and from that, get the value. From there you could opt to change that value and rebuild the string back.

Comment: @CharlesMay You know that SO is not here just to benefit the OP but future readers. Can you share your demo code with all?

Comment: Thanks @CharlesMay! I've just seen your E-mail, i'm kinda bussy this weekend but i will reply as fast as possible wether it worked or not ;)